# creating bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am trying to create a bibtex entry for:

> Alan Oppenheim. RES.6-008 Digital Signal Processing. Spring 2011.
>   Massachusetts Institute of Technology: MIT OpenCourseWare,
>   https://ocw.mit.edu. License: Creative Commons BY-NC-SA.

How can I do this? Which element should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I suggest to use the `@online` document type of `biblatex` to reference this online course material. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{key,
  author = {Alan Oppenheim},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Spring},
  title = {Digital Signal Processing},
  subtitle = {RES.6-008},
  url = {https://ocw.mit.edu},
  organization = {Massachusetts Institute of Technology: MIT OpenCourseWare},
  addendum = {License: Creative Commons BY-NC-SA}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Advances in integrated circuit technology have had a major impact on the technical areas to which digital signal processing techniques and hardware are being applied. (\cite{key})

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to change details of how the result should look like. See e.g. the [`biblatex` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) on further information.